# How to override a dynamically created setter method at runtime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, metaprogramming, dynamic-programming

Can anyone else help me with to pass one scenario that has to do with overriding a previously defined method?

I have a class that can receive a `Hash` to create instance variables at runtime for each key-value pairs. If the value is a `Hash` then we need to instantiate a new `Config` class and assign it to the instance variable in context and that is fixed on the `initialize` method.

Also, this class must respond to different methods and if they are not present then we need to create them on the fly. And this is covered by overriding the `method_missing` method and evaluate if the value for the given method is a `Hash` then apply the same logic as in the initializer.

```rb
class Config
  def initialize(parameters = {})
    raise ArgumentError.new unless parameters.is_a?(Hash)
    parameters.each do |key, value|
      raise ArgumentError.new unless key.is_a?(String) || key.is_a?(Symbol)
      create_new_method_on_instance(key, value)
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    name = method_name.to_s.delete_suffix('=')
    create_new_method_on_instance(name, args.first)
  end

  private

  def create_new_method_on_instance(name, value)
    singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}", Config.new(value))
    else
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

All that works just fine, but the problem is that now, I need to override the `foo` method on the fly. For example, first create a `Config.new({foo => 23})` object which will have a `foo` instance variable, then I want to pass a new value(reassign it) like this `config.foo = {x: 23}`.
Since this new value is a `hash`, then I need to intercept this and apply the same logic as before, create a new `Config` object with that value and assign it to the `foo` instance variable.

The problem here is that since the `foo` method is already defined, I can not intercept its new assignment in the `method_missing` method to apply the required logic.
Does anybody know a way to intercept when we call a setter method dynamically?

Tests:

```rb
describe 'VerifiedConfig' do
  it 'should return nil for non-existing config values' do
    config = Config.new

    expect(config.foo).to be_nil
    expect(config.bar).to be_nil
  end

  it 'should allow assigning new simple config values' do
    config = Config.new

    config.foo = 13
    config.bar = "foo-bar"

    expect(config.foo).to eq(13)
    expect(config.bar).to eq("foo-bar")
  end

  it 'should allow assigning hash values' do
    config = Config.new

    config.foo = {bar: {'baz' => 'x'}}
    config.bar = {'foo' => {bar: [12, 13], baz: 14}}

    expect(config.foo).to be_a(Config)
    expect(config.foo.bar).to be_a(Config)
    expect(config.foo.bar.baz).to eq('x')
    expect(config.bar.foo.bar).to eq([12, 13])
    expect(config.bar.foo.baz).to eq(14)
  end

  it 'should allow initialization through constructor' do
    config = Config.new({'foo' => {bar: [12, 13], baz: 14}})

    expect(config.foo.bar).to eq([12, 13])
    expect(config.foo.baz).to eq(14)
  end

  it 'should override values' do
    config = Config.new({'foo' => {bar: 'baz'}})

    config.foo = 10
    config.foo = {x: {y: 'z'}}

    expect(config.foo.x.y).to eq('z')
  end

  it 'should raise an error when keys have illegal type' do
    config = Config.new

    expect {config.x = {14 => 15}}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end

  it 'should not accept anything that Hash in the constructor' do
    expect {Config.new(11)}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    expect {Config.new('test')}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

This is the scenario that is failing:

```rb
it 'should override values' do
  config = Config.new({'foo' => {bar: 'baz'}})

  config.foo = 10
  config.foo = {x: {y: 'z'}}

  expect(config.foo.x.y).to eq('z')
end
```

**NOTE:** I can not use `OpenStruct`

Comment: Why can't you use `OpenStruct`? ...

Comment: I don't see any overriding anywhere in your code.

Comment: @TomLord Because that's a restriction on the exercise!

Comment: @JörgWMittag `method_missing` is being overridden, don´t you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the default getter and setter:

> ```rb
> singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
> ```

I suggest using a custom setter:

```rb
singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, name)
define_singleton_method("#{name}=") do |value|
  if value.is_a?(Hash)
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", Config.new(value))
  else
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
  end
end
public_send("#{name}=", value)
```

Comment: Thx, it worked like a charm! You are right, I should override the logic inside the setters methods so this can be executed whenever it is called and just right there decide what to do with the value to be assigned. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible way to solve it. It is a little bit similar but this works by **overriding** the `attr_accessor` method in the class.

I found it after posting this question and it works fine too:

```rb
class Config
  def initialize(parameters = {})
    raise ArgumentError.new unless parameters.is_a?(Hash)

    parameters.each do |key, value|
      raise ArgumentError.new unless key.is_a?(String) || key.is_a?(Symbol)

      create_accessor_methods_and_assign_value(key, value)
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    name = method_name.to_s.delete_suffix('=')
    create_accessor_methods_and_assign_value(name, args.first)
  end

  private

  def create_accessor_methods_and_assign_value(name, value)
    singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
    public_send("#{name}=", value)
  end

  def self.attr_accessor(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      # Create Getter method
      define_method(name) { instance_variable_get("@#{name}") }
      # Create Setter method
      define_method("#{name}=") do |arg|
        if arg.is_a?(Hash)
          instance_variable_set("@#{name}", Config.new(arg))
        else
          instance_variable_set("@#{name}", arg)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```